# webgl - babylonjs skybox texture not showing

Tags: textures, webgl, skybox, babylonjs

I have a problem with a texture of a skybox made in webgl using babylonjs.
My whole project is on the webserver and everything seemd to be good written but the box which should be a skybox doesn't show the texture - black outside and inside

code:

```
var skybox = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateBox("skyBox", 1000.0, scene);
var skyboxMaterial = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("skyBox", scene);
skyboxMaterial.backFaceCulling = false;
skyboxMaterial.reflectionTexture = new BABYLON.CubeTexture("skybox/skybox", scene);
skyboxMaterial.reflectionTexture.coordinatesMode = BABYLON.Texture.SKYBOX_MODE;
skyboxMaterial.diffuseColor = new BABYLON.Color3(0, 0, 0);
skyboxMaterial.specularColor = new BABYLON.Color3(0, 0, 0);
skybox.material = skyboxMaterial;
```

Comment: I have experienced a similar issue when using .png images. My hope is to use basis images but I think if .png isn't supported basis probably isn't either. Such a shame.

Comment: Yep only .jpg images are supported, what a shame.                                                                          `if (!isEnv && !isDDS && !extensions) {
    extensions = ["_px.jpg", "_py.jpg", "_pz.jpg", "_nx.jpg", "_ny.jpg", "_nz.jpg"];
}`

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your directory structure on disk is not correct for the skybox.

If you follow the babylon playground example for a skybox
http://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#3458P (and then download the zip for the complete working example)

You can see that in your case "skybox/skybox"
means a directory called "skybox" containing 6 skybox files i.e.

- "skybox" directory containing files named

  - skybox_nx.jpg
  - skybox_px.jpg
  - skybox_ny.jpg
  - skybox_py.jpg
  - skybox_nz.jpg
  - skybox_pz.jpg

Answer (score 1):

First check your fog, it will not let you see the skybox, try to remove it.
In my case was: I copied the code, and it was too big for my scene, I didn't notice the change. then I decrease the

```
    var skybox = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateBox("skyBox", 800.0, scene);
```

to

```
    var skybox = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateBox("skyBox", 52.5, scene);
```

and problem solved

Comment: I can't express how much that saved me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems right.
Could you check with F12 bar if the textures are correctly loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Simply add a free camera to solve this:

```
var freeCamera = new BABYLON.FreeCamera("FreeCamera", new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0, 5), scene);
scene.activeCamera = freeCamera;
```

You should see your skybox.
Thanks